# Include a file from a separate folder

Tags: php, include

[image]

Attached image shows the location of files it will help you to give answer. I want to include  `'db/functions.php'` in my file `'process/delete.php'` but nothing is working.
I have tried following at start of `'delete.php'`

```
include_once '/db/functions.php';
include_once './db/functions.php';
include_once '../db/functions.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db/functions.php';
```

When I open MAMP/log/php_error.log file it shows following error

```
[28-Jul-2012 21:55:23] PHP Warning:  include_once() 
[<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: 
Failed opening '/db/functions.php' for inclusion 
(include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php') in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/electromart/process/delete.php on line 3
```

Where line 3 is include statement.

Comment: You really need to learn how paths work. Your 3rd example (`../db/etc..`) is the one that SHOULD work. The other attempts are just flailing around in the dark.

Comment: Two questions: Is this on Linux? Is this your project structure and/or your server (docroot) structure?

Comment: I am working on Mac OS. Thanks @MarcB you were right, actually I was having another problem that's why I thought 3rd option is not working as well. Can you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error you could see the `electromart` folder is missing in the path and when you move to another machine the directory structure might change too depending on how the server is setup. Try

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/electromart/db/functions.php';
```

Comment: 'Source Files' is not an actual folder. Netbeans Categories all files under 'Source Files'. Actual location of file on Mac is 'Applications/MAMP/htdocs/electromart/db/functions.php. Replacing 'Source Files' with 'electromart' is working. Can you improve your answer. And include_once '../db/functions.php';
 is also working.

Comment: does `../db/functions.php` work for you in every files? I think you have to change that every time the relative position of the current file changes

Comment: and what does your `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` return?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `include_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."../db/functions.php");`

Comment: So make an absolute path to where the file already is, then go relative? Pointless...

Comment: It's not pointless. Although I would do it like this `require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../db/functions.php';`. From a security standpoint, it's more safer the way Arshdeep has done it. Take into account things like include paths, chdir() calls, virtual hosts, various subdomain setups, symlinks, the list goes on. Take example from OWASP ESAPI code at http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/source/browse/trunk/src/filters/SafeRequest.php